# Output scoped variable values within execution of batch/stored procedure TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, scope

Is it possible to output a list of all current variable values within the execution of a stored procedure?

For context, it would be nice to know what variable values are when a stored procedure throws an error to help troubleshooting. Of course you can manually put this logging with hardcoded variable values in a catch block, but that's not clean or transferable.

You can't use sys.parameters (even though it just does the parameters) as dynamic SQL won't work. Are there any built in variables or sys tables that store the current scope's variables that could be output during execution?

```
BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @Variable1 VARCHAR(64) = 'test'
    -- Do stuff
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    EXEC SpCustomLog @VariableValues = @Variable1 -- hardcoded
    EXEC sp_execute 'SELECT @Variable1'  -- not in scope/lost in build
END CATCH
```

Comment: AFAIK, this can't be done in T-SQL.  I'm curious how one would generically log all variables in the current scope in other programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using local variable, which is not possible to acess it out of it's scope. As [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx) also mentioned it:

> The scope of a variable is the range of Transact-SQL statements that
>   can reference the variable. The scope of a variable lasts from the
>   point it is declared until the end of the batch or stored procedure in
>   which it is declared. Variables have local scope and are only visible
>   within the batch or procedure where they are defined.

But you can use SQLCMD, to declare variable, which is accessible out of it's defined batch too(limited to the session!)

Here is the Code:

```
--deifne a variable using SQLCMD mode
:setvar myvar 10 
PRINT $(myvar)--accessible

GO

PRINT $(myvar)--Also accessible
```

In order to activate the SQLCMD mode, you need to select `SQLCMD mode` from `Query` menu.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know if there was some hidden table that might persist them. SQLCMD is an interesting point to make though, thanks for your input

Comment: Richard, Unfortunately, for the reasons stated above, there can be no table as these are temporary objects only brought into life within the scope of the process itself. You could, however scan through the syscomments.text and determine possible variables called into being, though this would take some level of coding to ensure you both account  for every variable and distinguish between Parameters, tables and variables, together with their data types.